# FFmpeg AVFrame Audio Data Modification

Tags: c, audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to figure out how FFmpeg saves data in an `AVFrame` after the audio has been decoded.

Basically, if I print the data in the `AVFrame->data[]` array I get a number of unsigned 8 bit integers that is the audio in raw format.

From what I can understand from the FFmpeg doxygen, the format of the data is expressed in the `enum AVSampleFormat` and there are 2 main categories: interleaved and planar. In the interleaved type, the data is all kept in the first row of the `AVFrame->data` array with size `AVFrame->linesize[0]` while in the planar type each channel of the audio file is kept in a separate row of the `AVFrame->data` array and the arrays have as size `AVFrame->linesize[0]`.

Is there a guide/tutorial that explains what do the numbers in the array mean for each of the formats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values in each of the `data` arrays (planes) are actual audio samples according to specified format. E.g. if format is `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P` it means that `data` arrays actually are arrays of `int16_t` PCM data. If we have deal with mono signal - only `data[0]` is valid, if it is stereo - `data[0]` and `data[1]` are valid, so on.

I'm not sure that there is any guide that can help you to explain each particular case but anyway described approach is quite simple and is easy to understand. You should just play a bit with it and thing should become clear.

Comment: If the array in the `AVFrame.h` is declared as `uint8_t`, how can `AVFrame->data` contain `int16_t`?

Comment: Just use cast: `int16_t *pcm16 =  (int16_t*) frame->data[0]`.

Comment: Is each of the elements in an array in `AVFrame->data` representing 1 audio sample?

Comment: Not exactly:) `data[N]` is a pointer to some data plane. `linesize[N]` is a number of bytes in some plane. E.g.  for `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P` if `linesize[0]` is `100` then `data[0]` is a pointer to `50` `int16_t` samples.

Comment: Does that mean that each sample is represented with 2 elements of the `data[0]` array?

Comment: No, it doesn't. As I said - actual type of sample is determined by `format` field and it may be 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit.

Comment: I understand. What I don't understand is why half of the `frame->data[0]` array would be empty if `linesize[0]` is 100

Comment: It is not empty. `linesize` is the number of bytes, not the number of samples in particular plane. If plane contains 16-bit PCM - 100 bytes is the size of 50 16-bit samples.